# Download HDF NDVI in R

Tags: r, modis, gdalutils

I have a function to automate downloading NDVI data from https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/

However, I'm hitting an error when downloading the .HDF files. They download fine but they seem to be corrupt, as I can't get any of the subdatasets using gdalUtils

Here is an example of the code, note that to download you will need an earthdata account:

```
library(gdalUtils)
library(utils)

usrname <- readline("EarthData username")
pwd <- readline("EarthData password")
link <- paste0("https://",usrname,":",pwd,"@e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD13Q1.005/2010.01.01/MOD13Q1.A2010001.h09v04.005.2010028053958.hdf")

#Now download
download.file(link,destfile=paste0("C:\\Temp_file\\MOD13Q1.A2010001.h09v04.005.2010028053958.hdf"),method='auto',quiet=F,cacheOK=T)

#Test to see if the download worked
gdalinfo("C:\\Temp_file\\MOD13Q1.A2010001.h09v04.005.2010028053958.hdf")
```

The full error I get from gdalinfo is:

```
[1]"ERROR 4: `C:\\Temp_file\\MOD13Q1.A2010001.h09v04.005.2010028053958.hdf' 
not recognized as a supported file format."
[2] ""                                                                                                             
[3] "gdalinfo failed - unable to open 
'C:\\Temp_file\\MOD13Q1.A2010001.h09v04.005.2010028053958.hdf'."                  
 attr(,"status")
 [1] 1
```

Why I think my mistake is in 'download.file' is that if I download manually the hdf file and try "gdalinfo" again, the file is able to be opened and looks correct.

I'm aware of the 'ModisDownload' function in the rts package. For my purposes it will be much more convenient if I had a function so that I can personalize it to my needs.

Comment: Have you tried `download.file(..., method = "wget")` (or alternatively `"curl"`)? That's the way we realized it in **MODIS** when the user chooses to download from LP DAAC ([ln. 705](https://github.com/MatMatt/MODIS/blob/develop/R/minorFuns.R) onwards) and it works just fine.

Comment: Does the downloaded file look reasonably large? It might just be an error message response or a redirect from the server that `download.file` isn't responding to. Can you redo it with `quiet=FALSE` and edit the output into your question - it might give us some clues.

Comment: The hdf file from `download.file` is 173 MB, which is reasonable to me. But, I will note that when I download the exact same tile on the same date manually, the hdf file is _slightly_ smaller by 700 KB.
When I try `download.file(...,method='wget')` instead of `method=auto` I get an error
`Error in download.file(link,destination_file,method='wget',:
'wget'  call had nonzero exit status
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'wget' had status 127`

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Not really an answer, but you could also have a look at package `MODIStsp`.